# PHP: how to extract wrapped content of a .p7m file?

Tags: php, openssl, p7m

We receive a lot of p7m files, "wrapped Cades" only.

We need to extract content from p7m.

I am able to do manually using an hex editor, cutting before and after the PDF content, or using `openssl` command.

Is there a way to do it using php ? I can see `openssl` extension but I'm not able to figure out a simple extraction method.

> Note: Content is wrapped, not crypted.

I am amble to find python only answers, like this

- [get p7m file content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65994406/get-p7m-file-content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a perfect package on github

https://github.com/filippotoso/p7m-extractor

It does exactly what I need. And it works in Laravel (I tried it on laravel 9)

```
    use FilippoToso\P7MExtractor\P7M;

    .....

    $success = (new P7M("<full path to openssl executable>"))
        ->setSource($pathToFileToExtract)
        ->setDestination($pathToExtractedPdf)
        ->save()
    ;
```

It *requires* your system has an openssl.exe already installed.
It easy to find a windows build here: https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html